# Rails simple drop down menu with collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I am trying to put together what I thought should be a simple task.

A drop down menu from a collection. All I want it to do is have the user pick the location press submit (no java) and it goes to the associated show page.

This is what I have:

```
<%= form_tag installation_path(), :method => 'get' do %>
<%= select_tag 'installation_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@installations, "id", "name") %>
<%= submit_tag "Go", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

I can not figure out how to simply pass the selected location id to the action path. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Can anyone give me an example of how to make this work? When I put an action it throws an error.

Comment: post the `action` where this form will get submitted

Comment: Might also be helpful to post the `params`.

Comment: When I post an action it causes an error.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think @RAJ meant to edit your question to include the `action` that contains the code that receives the form request on submission.

Comment: yeah @mmichael got it right... @looloobs, please add `action` code you your question

Comment: Oh sorry, so I assumed (clearly wrong) that the installation_path would call the show action. Do I need a custom action? I played around with that earlier, but that seemed silly since all I want is to call installations/1. I feel like I must be making this way to complicated.

Comment: Typically, you want to pass an object to a `show` action like `installation_path(@installation)` so you can grab the object in your controller (i.e. `params[:id]`).